# is there a way in scala i can form a map based on the content of two arrays

Tags: scala, dictionary, mapping, immutability

I have two scala vectors
value - represents values
occurrences - represents number of occurrences of a character
Ex:

values : (a,b,c,d)
occurrences : (4,2,1,5)

How can I merge this two vectors into Map of form Map[Char,Int)] = Map(a -> 4,b->2,c->1,d->5)

Answer (score 5):

```
(values zip occurrences).toMap
```

`zip` pairs up matching elements in two collections, and `toMap` converts a collection of pairs into a `Map`.

Comment: it would be good to use `lazyZip` or `values.iterator.zip(occurrences).toMap` to avoid the intermediate collection.